# Share accounts by field value

Tags: sharing, partner-communities, sharing-rule, visibility

I need to share account's (read access) based on a lookup on account.

I have a community of partners in which I have two profiles, manager and promoter. All promoters should have read access at the same level ff a promoter creates a record, another promoter should be able to see that record as long as they have the same value in a lookup.

for example:
if the logged community user (User.Contact.Account = exampleId), this user should be able to see all the accounts that have a lookup custom field equals exampleId.

I know it's possible but I do not remember how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [Sharing Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customer_portal_sharing_set.htm&type=5) here.

> Grant portal or community users access, based on their user profiles, to records that are associated with their accounts or contacts using sharing sets.

You can use it with the objects listed in the documentation or any custom object.